# Rails: Any way to "move" folder to another directory instead of "copying" that folder in Amazon S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

Right now I'm using the ['aws-s3' gem](https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3) & I'm only seeing a "copy" method. Copying a folder to another directory seems like it would cost me more, take longer, & just less efficient (I'm not sure how S3's copying method works). Can anyone who has experience with this gem or a similar gem or maybe just experience in Amazon's S3 & Rails overall, shed some light?

How would I go about moving a folder instead of copying it in Amazon S3, using Rails?

Thanks in advance

---

Nothing? I've been at it for days now..

Comment: Move doesn't exist. You have to copy and then delete the original.

Comment: I'm assuming that would cost me more & would take longer. Is there a gem that allows me to move the file instead of copying it?

Comment: No, that doesn't exist. It's a limitation of S3. As you can see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectOps.html) there is no `move` in the S3 API. Sorry.

Comment: Darn... Thanks anyway..